# need some statistics questions answered

Tags: statistics, linear-regression

Hi im having some trouble with these 2 problems. 11 a. I am not sure if there is a accurate anser needed for this question but still would like to hear what will be the ideal answer for this. 11 b. I said y=202.53+1.4gx
11 c. I said "around 47% of the dots are around the regression line.
11 d. I said "the value of correlation between calories and sodium is moderate.
11 e. I said "the prediction is not reliable.

12 a. I said "No because there is a leftover curved pattern.
12 b. I said "It means when using the lease square regression line with x to predict y will typically be off by about 23.
12 c. I said "-1.993, for every lunch, it will be decreased by -1.993
12 d. I said -57.9.

Please correct them and provide me what I SHOULD have said

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zL9OG.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7ejg8.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cZTe1.png)

Comment: • Please craft an *informative* title, that refers to the specifics of the question.  • Never post unsearchable images of text or equations; take the time to typeset it (in *MathJax*).  •.Is this a homework problem?  This is not a site for that.

Comment: @DavidG.Stork : One can ask questions about homework problems here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For $(c)$ the usual "interpretation" is that about $47\%$ of the variability in the level of sodium is "explained" by the variability in calories. The other $53\%$ is variability in the residuals.

In $(d)$, possibly the request for a comment on the reliability could be satisfied by a prediction interval or the like. Formulas for these are found in most textbooks.